# Turn an iterator into a scalar index?

Tags: c++, iterator

Is there a way to determine the position of an iterator inside it's container?  The "position" I'm looking would take the form of an integer value, that describes how far from the beginning of the container the iterator is.

For example,`vector.front()` would be `0`, and `vector.back()` would be `vector.size() - 1`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance):

```
size_t index = std::distance( vector.begin(), it );
```

What it does behind the scenes is just `it - v.begin()` (for random access iterators, such as vector's). Otherwise, it just increments first argument until it reaches the second (which isn't particularly efficient).